# When a hashSet collision happens, what method is invoked first to compare the objects?

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashset

I have seen 2 versions of the procedure on the internet for what happens when there is a collision.

Version 1 (the most seen one):

> When there IS an element already at that specific position of the array, invoke equals() to check if they are the same: If yes, insertion denied. If not, insert the new element.

Version 2 :

> When there IS an element already at that specific position of the
> array, invoke hashCode() method to compare their hashCode. If their
> hashCode is different,insert the new element. If they are the same,
> then invoke equals() and do the same as the first version.

I wonder which one is correct in Java8.

Comment: Both are wrong. What's "that specific position of the array" supposed to be? There are no arrays. Calculate the hashcode, this determines which bucket the item resides within. Kind of a modulus. Compare it to all the items in that bucket with `equals`. If it matches none, insert it. The structure of a bucket is either a List or a red-black tree, depending on the size.

Comment: Your versions could do with being more precise - e.g. what do "the array" and the "specific position" refer to in Version 2?  From my guesses this process wouldn't make any sense - but it's just as likely I'm guessing wrong as anything else.  If you tighten up the description you'll get better answers.

Comment: Your question is 'which one is correct in Java8'. The answer is that any implementation that meets the standard is correct. Specifically "This class offers constant time performance for the basic operations (add, remove, contains and size), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets." There are many ways to implement this standard and none of them are any more 'correct' than any other.

Answer (score 0):

We can inspect the JDK source code to answer this question. Looking at the [HashSet](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk8-b120/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/HashSet.java) implementation we can see that it is basically a wrapper over HashMap, using the Map's keyset to implement the Set.

Moving to the [HashMap](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk8-b120/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java) implementation, [we can see](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk8-b120/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#L646-L648) that both hashcode and equals are checked, however hashcode happens first and will short circuit the evaluation if true.

A similar thing happens in the case of the Map being backed by a red-black tree (see the `putTreeVal` method's implementation).

Comment: Just wanted to add a correction to this answer. By 'the JDK source code' you mean 'OpenJDK's reference implementation of the Java standard'. This is an important caveat: different implementations of the standard do not need to implement exactly the same way (as long as they conform to the standard).

Comment: @sprinter You are right and this is an important point to take note of.